# How to delete rows that exceed a certain amount of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working on putting csv files into a dataframe and loading it into a database, but there are a few files that have rows with data in extra columns. I want to be able to drop the entire row that exceeds 'X' amount of columns

Example, want to remove rows that have more than 4 columns

```
id, header1, header2, header3
1, desc1, desc2, desc3
2, desc1, desc2, desc3
3, desc1, desc2, desc3, desc4
4, desc1, desc2, desc3
```

I would like to skip row with id = 3,
output:

```
id, header1, header2, header3
1, desc1, desc2, desc3
2, desc1, desc2, desc3
4, desc1, desc2, desc3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas can do it for you, use `on_bad_lines='skip'` as parameter of `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', on_bad_lines='skip')
print(df)

# Output
   id header1 header2 header3
0   1   desc1   desc2   desc3
1   2   desc1   desc2   desc3
2   4   desc1   desc2   desc3
```

**Update**

For older versions of Pandas, use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
print(df)

# Output
   id header1 header2 header3
0   1   desc1   desc2   desc3
1   2   desc1   desc2   desc3
2   4   desc1   desc2   desc3
```

Comment: Kept getting error 'parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines'

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('/user/file/data.csv', on_bad_lines='skip',
                  sep=',', 
                  names=['id', 'header1', 'header2', 'header3' ])

Comment: You have an old version of Pandas. You should update. What is your version? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: Tried it but doesn't drop the entire row, just that single value. I have version 0.24.2

Comment: Can you update your version of pandas?

Comment: Yup updated version, still only dropping that single value instead of the entire row

Comment: Did you test without `names` parameter? It worked with your sample.